Unable to import pymesh2 despite package being installed in environment
In my virtual environment, I import pymesh2, but I get an error:

no module pymesh2

But when I use conda list pymesh2, it displays the version and other information:
(cnc) ~$ which conda /home/lc/anaconda3/condabin/conda
(cnc) ~$ which python /home/lc/anaconda3/envs/cnc/bin/python

It seems like which conda can find the path inside of "condabin", not "bin". But inside the .bashrc, the path checks the "bin" directory:
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/lc/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)" if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup" else
    if [ -f "/home/lc/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/lc/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/lc/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi fi unset __conda_setup <<< conda initialize <<<export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin

I am not familiar with this error, what could be the cause?
